# Building an API on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, aws-api-gateway, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I'm building an app and the idea is to go serverless.

I'm looking mainly at AWS and GCP (Google Cloud Platform), and as AWS costs are a bit obscure (at least for me), and there is no way to ensure not being billed, I'm going with GCP.

For the "server" part of the app, I would like to build an API on GCP as I could do with AWS API Gateway, but I couldn't find any matching product for that.

The closer one was Google Cloud Endpoint, but it seems to have a very different concept from AWS API Gateway. I've watched some videos about it (for example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bR9hEyZ9774), but still can't get the idea behind it or if it fits my needs.

Could someone please help clarify which GCP product would be suitable for creating an API and how it compares to AWS API Gateway?

Some link with info/example on how to do it would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Google Product Manager here.

We don't have an exact analog for AWS API Gateway.

You're right about Cloud Endpoints. It's a bit of a different architecture than AWS uses -- it's a sidecar proxy that gets deployed with the backend. That's different than API Gateway, which is a fully managed proxy deployed in front of your backends.

If you are deploying in App Engine Flexible environments: good news! The Endpoints Proxy can be deployed as part of your deployment. It can do things similar to AWS API Gateway (API key validation, JWT validation, rate limiting).

We *are* working on some plans to allow for the proxy to be used in other places (Cloud Functions and the newer App Engine Standard runtimes).

And, finally: on our older App Engine Java and Python runtimes, we have API Frameworks that provide the same functionality. Those frameworks do the same thing as the proxy, but get expressed as code annotations and built into your app. We're moving *away* from the framework model in favor of the proxy model.

Comment: Hello Product Manager, can you share any update on how to accomplish building an API Server in 2019? I've found that there is a lot of confusion on the building block concepts necessary for this task and the documentation is inadequate.

Answer (score 0):

An example of springboot project with google cloud app engine can be found here-https://github.com/ashishkeshu/googlecloud-springboot